# How to get current date in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to get the current date in Helm with the following format YY-MM-DD. I'm trying `{{ now | date }}` but this returns an error because the number of arguments expected by date is two, not one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Format the date to YEAR-MONTH-DAY:

```
{{ now | date "20060102150405" }}
```

Source [here](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/date.html):

or add the following annotation :

```
annotations:
   deploymentTime: {{ now | date "2006-01-02T15:04:05" }}
```

Comment: I've used {{ now | date "2006-01-02" }} and it works so thank you!

Comment: Curious why this is working when I have date format like "2024-03-18T08:30:00"? but works for "2006-01-02T15:04:05".